# What is PassthroughSubject & CurrentValueSubject

Tags: ios, swiftui, reactive-programming, combine, declarative-programming

I happen to look into Apple's new Combine framework, where I see two things

`PassthroughSubject<String, Failure>`

`CurrentValueSubject<String, Failure>`

Can someone explain to me what is meaning & use of them?

Comment: You can start from here [Using Combine](https://heckj.github.io/swiftui-notes/#aboutthisbook) - very helpful.

Answer (score 187):

I think we can make analogies with real world cases.

**PassthroughSubject = A doorbell push button**

When someone rings the door, you are notified only if you are at home (you are the subscriber)

PassthroughSubject doesn't have a state, it emits whatever it receives to its subscribers.

**CurrentValueSubject = A light switch**
Someone turns on the lights in your home when you are outside. You get back home and you know someone has turned them on.

CurrentValueSubject has an initial state, it retains the data you put in as its state.

Comment: That's the best analogy I have seen so far. Thank you!

Answer (score 97):

Both `PassthroughSubject` and `CurrentValueSubject` are publishers that conform to the `Subject` protocol which means you can call `send` on them to push new values downstream at will.

The main difference is that `CurrentValueSubject` has a sense of state (current value) and `PassthroughSubject` simply relays values directly to its subscribers without remembering the "current" value:

```
var current = CurrentValueSubject<Int, Never>(10)
var passthrough = PassthroughSubject<Int, Never>()

current.send(1)
passthrough.send(1)

current.sink(receiveValue: { print($0) })
passthrough.sink(receiveValue: { print($0) })
```

You'd see that the `current.sink` is called immediately with `1`. The `passthrough.sink` is not called because it has no current value. The sink will only be called for values that are emitted after you subscribe.

Note that you can also get and set the current value of a `CurrentValueSubject` using its `value` property:

```
current.value // 1
current.value = 5 // equivalent to current.send(5)
```

This isn't possible for a passthrough subject.

Comment: That's a not good example for `PassthroughSubject`. You are ignoring the cancellable return on `passthrough.sink(receiveValue: { print($0) })`, so it will never print anything, even if you send some value afterward. You should save the return to a variable.

Comment: That's not correct. Since all of this runs synchronously, the initial value of 1 will be printed immediately.

You'd be correct if the subscription needs to be longer lived but for demonstrating the difference between the two subjects this is perfectly fine.

Comment: the value 1 comes from the `CurrentValueSubject`. If you add the code `passthrough.send(90)` on the last line, you will never get 90 printed. That's my point.

Answer (score 19):

`PassthroughSubject` is used for representing events. Use it for events like button tap.

`CurrentValueSubject` is used representing state. Use it for storing any value, say state of switch as off and on.

Note: `@Published` is kind of `CurrentValueSubject`.

Answer (score 12):

`PassthroughSubject` and `CurrentValueSubject` are both `Publisher`s — a type introduced by Combine — that you can subscribe to (performing operations on values when values are available).

They both are designed to make it easy to transfer to using the Combine paradigm. They both have a value and an error type, and you can "send" values to them (making the values available to all subscribers)

The main difference between the two that I've seen is that `CurrentValueSubject` starts with a value, while `PassthroughSubject` does not. `PassthroughSubject` seems easier to grasp conceptually, at least for me.

`PassthroughSubject` can easily be used in place of a delegate pattern, or to convert an existing delegate pattern to Combine.

```swift
//Replacing the delegate pattern
class MyType {
    let publisher: PassthroughSubject<String, Never> = PassthroughSubject()

    func doSomething() {
        //do whatever this class does

        //instead of this:
        //self.delegate?.handleValue(value)

        //do this:
        publisher.send(value)
    }
}

//Converting delegate pattern to Combine
class MyDel: SomeTypeDelegate {
    let publisher: PassthroughSubject<String, Never> = PassthroughSubject()

    func handle(_ value: String) {
        publisher.send(value)
    }
}
```

Both of these examples use `String` as the type of the value, while it could be anything.

Hope this helps!

Comment: PassthroughSubject<(String, Bool), Never>() is the shorter version

Answer (score 5):

`PassthroughSubject` is suitable for event like tap action

`CurrentValueSubject` is suitable for state

Answer (score 1):

Already a lot of good answers posted in this thread, just thought of adding this answer for someone who is coming from using RxSwift.

`PassThroughSubject` is like `PublishSubject` where it broadcasts an event to its subscribers, probably with some value passed along.

`CurrentValueSubject` is similar to `BehaviorRelay` where a single value is persisted with the subject instance and passed along during the event broadcast.

Answer (score 1):

**CurrentValueSubject** and **PassthroughSubject** are two subjects in combine  and both are publishers which means subscriber can subscribe these publishers and can listen for emitted events.

Both are different in terms of how they behave with their subscribers which are listening to them. Let's discuss both individually

**CurrentValueSubject** says please give me some initial value on subject creation. Like as below code

```
var disposeBag = [AnyCancellable]()  
var subject : CurrentValueSubject<String, Never> = CurrentValueSubject("Mashhood")
```

While subscribing to subject

```
subject.subscribe(on: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background))
    .sink { value in
       print(value)
    }
    .store(in: &disposeBag)
```

As subscriber subscribe that subject it will immediately receive current value that is

**OUTPUT**

> Mashhood

And as we send another value like as

```
subject.send("Qadeer")
```

then output looks like as

**OUTPUT**

> Mashhood

> Qadeer

**Conclusion**
Subscriber subscribing have following points

- *It will always get a value on subscription it can be value given in subject creation in case if **no value sent to subject***  but if something sent to subject before subscribing then it will be received on subscription as most recent value.
- *It will get most recent value on subscription as discussed in first point and each value submitted after subject subscription.*

Now Let's discuss the **PassthroughSubject** the PassthroughSubject subject **does not have initial value** on subject creation like as

```
var passThroughSubject: PassthroughSubject<String, Never> = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>()
```

Code for sending value and subscription

```
passThroughSubject.send("Mashhood")
passThroughSubject.subscribe(on: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background))
    .sink { value in
       dump(value)
    }
    .store(in: &disposeBag)
passThroughSubject.send("Qadeer")
```

**OUTPUT**

> Qadeer

As you can see it will print only event value that happened after it's subscription. And it **does not know about the previous event values**.

**Conclusion**
Subscriber subscribing have following points

- *It does not take initial value on subject creation.*
- *It will get value for an event happened after it's subscription and not know about the first most recent event before it's subscription*